# Auto Post - Share Article On LinkedIn and Google+

Tags: facebook, twitter, google-plus, linkedin-api

I am trying to auto post(without any authentication) an article on social sites like twitter, facebook, linkedin and google+. For facebook and twitter, auto post sharing is working. But for linkedin and google+, i am working continuously but no luck. Kindly help me if anyone of you suffers from the same.

*Note : Authentication not allowed, directly share to linkedin and google+.*

Comment: At least Facebook doesn’t allow you to “auto-post.” And how is that supposed to work without authentication anyway? You can most certainly not be talking about using the official APIs then?

Comment: @CBroe, i have posted the article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For facebook and twitter, auto post is already working for me. Now linkedin auto post is also working without any authentication only access token needs to gets authenticate.

I follow https://github.com/Happyr/LinkedIn-API-client to achieve my objective.